# get hours from full date date to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I work with api in python3 in this api return date like this

```
'Jun 29, 2018 12:44:14 AM'
```

but i need just hours, minute ad second like this

```
12:44:14
```

are there a fonction that can format this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the output is a string. So, you can use string slicing:

```
x = 'Jun 29, 2018 12:44:18 AM'
time = x[-11:-3]
```

It's best to use negative indexing here because the day may be single-digit or double-digit, so a solution like `time = x[13:21]` won't work every time.

If you're inclined, you may wish to use `strptime()` and `strftime()` to take your string, convert it into a datetime object, and then convert that into a string in HH:MM:SS format. (You may wish to consult the [datetime module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for this approach).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `datetime` module. Use `.strptime()` to convert string to datetime object and then `.strftime()` to convert to your required string output. Your sample datetime string is represented as `'%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p'`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
s = 'Jun 29, 2018 12:44:14 AM'
print( datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p').strftime("%H:%M:%S") )
```

**Output:**

```
12:44:14
```